# Python local and global variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def f():
    global s
    print s
    s = "That's clear."
    print s     

s = "Python is great!" 
f()
print s
```

Output:

```
Python is great!
That's clear.
That's clear.
```

as per program, the last print statement should return "s= Python is great" because I think here S should be referred Global variable.

Comment: It is, but you gave it a new value in `f()`. Globals can be accessed and modified in any scope. If you want the last print to output "Python is great", then you should *not* declare `s` a global.

Comment: No, you just updated it in your function. It would still be "Python is great!" if you hadn't declared it as global in f.

Comment: You have changed the value of global variable 's'  in the function 'f()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is correct. After `s` is defined as a global variable, you print the value assigned to s at that point which is `Python is great`, then you assign `That's clear.` to `s` - `s` is now global, so when you assign `That's clear.` to it inside your function, that becomes it's value in the outer scope as well.

Here is a good stackoverflow answer regarding [Scoping Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules).

Answer (score 2):

You modified the global variable in your function (f) so the variable now has the value that you modified at last
i.e. "That's clear."